# jQuery for each selected element runs together

Tags: jquery

I would like to make jQuery script for fading elements.

But, when i hover 1 of the `<a class='sow'></a>` elements. The jQuery affects all of the
`<a class='sow'></a>` elements. 
For example, when i hover the first selected element, the other elements is also affected (fading).

What i want : when i hover the selected element, the other elements does not affected.

Script:

```
$(".sow").hover(
function() {
  $(".leftinf").show( "slow" );
  $(".rightinf").show( "slow" );
},
function() {
  $(".leftinf").hide( "slow" );
  $(".rightinf").hide( "slow" );
})
```

How can i fix this?

#sorry for my bad english :/

The blog of which containing the code abov: [www.howtopc.cf](http://www.howtopc.cf)

Comment: Can you post a fiddle of your code? Especially the HTML part

Comment: [http://pastebin.com/HgFJc87m]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `$(this)` object at this context,

```
$(".sow").hover(function() {
  $(".leftinf,.rightinf", $(this).next(".informasi")).show("slow");
},function() {
  $(".leftinf,.rightinf", $(this).next(".informasi")).hide("slow");
});
```

- The `.next()` function will select the immediate next sibling.
- The `$("selector", context)` will select the element based on
  selector in the provided context.

Comment: @ArifZoel Are you sure, you have used the code given by me? Can you show how you used my code here? Just paste it here

Comment: @ArifZoel Created a demo for you, hover over the `test` in it. https://jsfiddle.net/ouubhgje/

Comment: Thanks! it works, i think the error caused by my connection :D

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to avoid this thing is that, you should target elements on the basis of id and not on the basis of class, so try targetting by id ,this may solve your problem.
In case you want to target it by class Try this:

HTML :

```
<button id="button">
  Button
</button>
<div class="mainDiv">
 <div class="leftinf">
  Left Inf
 </div>

 <div class="rightinf">
  Right Inf
 </div>
</div>
```

JQuery :

```
$("#button").hover(function() {
   $(".mainDiv").toggle();
});
```

I guess this will solve your problem, go through this.
Working Fiddle : [Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/cwqqbLv7/2/)

Comment: So you want everyone to set id for all the elements instead of a class? o_0 ?

Comment: @ArifZoel Try this code and check whether it works for you or not